# Connecting two slider components to act as one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, slider

I'm new to React Native and I'm currently trying to make a Split functionality where the user can adjust the percentage of each person. If both the percentages add up to 100%, the slider cannot move further for any person, but can be lowered in order to increase the other persons percentage.

I'm using the [react-native-slider](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-slider) library to achieve this.

So far I've tried the following to achieve this:

Snack Link: https://snack.expo.dev/@jay_m/delicious-chip?platform=android

Code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';

const SplitBillPage = () => {
  const [range, setRange] = useState('50%');
  const [secondRange, setSecondRange] = useState('50%');
  const [maxValue, setMaxValue] = useState('1');
  const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
  const [maxSecondValue, setMaxSecondValue] = useState('1');

  function rangeSetter(value) {
    setRange(parseInt(value * 100) + '%');
    let x = range;
    let y = secondRange;
    let withoutPercentage = x.replace('%', '');
    let withoutPercentageSecond = y.replace('%', '');
    if (
      parseInt(withoutPercentage) + parseInt(withoutPercentageSecond) ==
      100
    ) {
      setDisable(true);
    }
  }

  function rangeSetterSecond(value) {
    setSecondRange(parseInt(value * 100) + '%');
    let x = range;
    let y = secondRange;
    let withoutPercentage = x.replace('%', '');
    let withoutPercentageSecond = y.replace('%', '');
    if (parseInt(withoutPercentage) + parseInt(withoutPercentageSecond) < 100) {
      setDisable(false);
    } else if (
      parseInt(withoutPercentage) + parseInt(withoutPercentageSecond) ==
      100
    ) {
      setDisable(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{range}</Text>
      <Slider
        style={{width: 200, height: 40}}
        minimumValue={0}
        value={0.5}
        disabled={disable}
        maximumValue={1}
        minimumTrackTintColor="darkblue"
        maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
        onValueChange={value => rangeSetter(value)}
      />
      <Text>{secondRange}</Text>
      <Slider
        style={{width: 200, height: 40}}
        minimumValue={0}
        value={0.5}
        maximumValue={1}
        minimumTrackTintColor="darkblue"
        maximumTrackTintColor="#000000"
        onValueChange={value => rangeSetterSecond(value)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default SplitBillPage;
```

Now there are a few problems that come with this:

1. Here for some reason the sliders dont work sometimes, they sometimes stop when the 2 equal to 100% but sometimes they keep going.
2. Here I only found a way to stop the user from adjusting the slider is by disabling it, but then that means that the user wont even be able to lower it as the slider is now disabled. Hence I only put the disable feature in the first slider so that it can be adjusted again when the second one is lowered which is not what I want.

P.S: The expo snack emulator isn't disabling the slider when it runs, but when I tried it with my systems emulator, it disables...

Comment: Library currently doesn't supports controlling slider position, because without that we can't stop the slider from moving past the point. (but we can control the total value to not exceed 1 by simply updating the individual states only when total value doesn't exceed 1.

Also, the PR is already raised (with all tests passing) for above use case: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-slider/pull/432